# How to prevent added texture from appearing on multiple sides of mesh when using generated coordinates?

Tags: texturing, uv, shaders, shader-nodes

I have a mesh that I would like to apply a decal to. I add the decal in as an emission shader and use a mix shader node with the alpha as the factor to easily make the decal appear on the side of the object. Then I use a texture coordinate (generated) node and mapping node to scale and reposition the decal to the correct size. This all works perfectly.

However, the decal appears on both the front and back of the object, even when set to not repeat. It only shows up once, but appears on both sides of the mesh.

[image: Correct Example]
This is the side I want the decal on, and it works and looks fine.

[image: Incorrect Example]
But it is also appearing on the backside and is inverted, something I do not want.

**Does anyone have any ideas on how to prevent this from occurring?**

I will also attach my node tree.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about your workflow, but if its only in blender then you can use a gradient map to divide the gun in two where one half is black and one half is white, then you can use that gradient texture as a mask to mask out the logo on the other side.[image]

Comment: Thank you for that idea. I will try to do it that way if I cannot find another way. I was more interested in why exactly the texture is being applied to both sides in the first place so I can avoid that happening in the future.

Comment: because of generated coordinates , all it does is projects the cords on to your mesh from an angle like pasting your decal on glass. if you look from one side its normal. if you look from other side its flipped.

Comment: Is there a way to project the texture onto the mesh without it displaying that behavior? I tried with object coordinates and got the same result.

Comment: if its only projection, just go to the side view of the mesh in edit mode , press U and Project from View. This will give you flat uvs for the rifle . now in edit mode select the other half and scale the uvs of the 2nd half and move it somewhere else.